# suitable name for function/method

Tags: c#, java, oop

I have class with method that inside of it i take complex object and 
from it I create new object with simple structure user can work with it
in more convenient way .I store this object instance in the memory and
and provide simple api to it.
I give it name **Serializable** but I'm not sure that this is the right name.

Comment: C# or Java? You've tagged both.

Comment: Wow. Three up votes, two answers, and question closed, all in less than five minutes.

Comment: They're not that different... @techfoobar

Answer (score 2):

- `Transform`
- `TransformToX` (where `X` is the name of the resulting object)
- `ToX` (you see that a lot, for instance, `ToString`, `ToInt32`)

Answer (score 2):

I name methods like that using names like `asThing()`. I suppose in C# it should be `AsThing()`. Another choice might be to follow the example of Java's `Number` class: `Number.intValue()`, etc.